How to fix the error cannot convert the series to <class 'float'>
I have a excel data .xslx, with 4 columns and many rows and I just want to extract the column 0 that is my wavelength and the 3 column that is my radiation, and I make a pyplots from that data. My archive looks like this
280.0   8.2000E-02  4.7309E-23  2.5361E-26
280.5   9.9000E-02  1.2307E-21  1.0917E-24
281.0   1.5000E-01  5.6895E-21  6.1253E-24
281.5   2.1200E-01  1.5662E-19  2.7479E-22
282.0   2.6700E-01  1.1946E-18  2.8346E-21
282.5   3.0300E-01  4.5436E-18  1.3271E-20

Next I want to use curve_fit to adjust a black body to the peplos using Planck's equation.
But when I use curve fit I got an error:
File"/Applications/Spyder.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python3.9/pandas/core/series.py", line 191, in wrapper
raise TypeError(f"cannot convert the series to {converter}")

 TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'float'>    

This error comes when the program try to calculate the covariance.
I tried to change my radiation nd wavelength using astype(float) but it doesn't work.
import pandas as pd
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.constants import h, c, k
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
Data=pd.read_excel('Sun_Data.xlsx', sheet_name='Spectra',header=2) 
#fname='Sun_Data.txt' 
#A=np.loadtxt(fname)

wavelength=Data.iloc[:,0].astype(float)
rad=Data.iloc[:,3].astype(float)

#wave=list(wavelength)
#print(wave)
def funcion(wavelegth,T):
    planck=(2*math.pi*c**2*h)/(wavelength**5*(math.exp(h*c/(wavelength*k*T))-1))
    return planck

#print(funcion(wavelength, rad))
t,cov=curve_fit(funcion, wavelength, rad)
plt.plot(wavelength,rad, color='pink')
plt.show()

I think my error is using pandas to read the data but I'm not sure, can someone
help me.

Please post the full traceback of the error.

Here is
File "/Applications/Spyder.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python3.9/pandas/core/series.py", line 191, in wrapper
raise TypeError(f"cannot convert the series to {converter}")
TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'float'>

Put it in the question, so you can format it properly in a code block.

Have you printed wavelength and rad so you know what you actually read?

@TimRoberts yes the program read it

isolate your problem & provide [mre] (read notice)

That's not at all what I asked.  Which line does the error occur on?  There's so much you haven't told us.

I update it, the error comes when the program try to return the Planck's function and the error's in the covariance too


TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'float'> is an error that occurs because you entered a series where you should have passed a float. It is not caused by your failure to convert the series to a series with a dtype of float. (A series with a dtype of float is still a series of class)



looking at your user-defined function funcion, I see that it takes a series as an argument, but it looks like you created funcion thinking that it would be passed a float, which is an individual element of the series. That seems to be the reason for the error.


If you isolate your function fucion and try it with multiple arguments, you'll see that the same error occurs. Isolation is key to solving coding problems.

run this code: math.exp(pd.Series([0.1, 0.2, 0.3])) -> same error

curve_fit signature is curve_fit(f, xdata, ydata), where x has multiple columns and y - only one, and y=function(x[0], x[1], x[2]... , *params) + eps
If your rad columns means values for different temperatures, you  should pass it one by one:
t1, cov1 = curve_fit(funcion, wavelength, rad[:, 0])
t2, cov2 = curve_fit(funcion, wavelength, rad[:, 1])
t3, cov3 = curve_fit(funcion, wavelength, rad[:, 2])

